# How to return the result of a stored procedure into a list in my view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my first question here and I'm new to WPF/MVVM.

What I'm trying to do is display a multi-column listview that holds the results returned from a stored procedure.

I'm doing my best to implement MVVM and this is where I'm having trouble.

I have a model (`SL_ID` is the PK and not nullable in the database):

```
public class mJob_Select_OrderList
{
        public int SL_ID { get; set; }
        public string E32JobNumber { get; set; }
        public string E32_CLIENT { get; set; }
        public string SL_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public string E32_DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
}
```

and then I have a view model:

```
public class vmJob_Select : vmMain
{
        #region Members
        Models.mJob_Select _mJobSelectSettings;
        public SLEVEN_CLASS.dbSLEVENDataContext _dc;
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public vmJob_Select()
        {
            _dc = new SLEVEN_CLASS.dbSLEVENDataContext();

            _mJobSelectSettings = new Models.mJob_Select { EnvironmentID = 1 };

            //EnvironmentList
            var dsEnvironmentList = (from el in _dc.vw_EnvironmentLists orderby el.ENV_ID select new mJob_Select_Environment { ENV_ID = el.ENV_ID, Environment = el.Environment, IMAGE_RESOURCE = el.IMAGE_RESOURCE });
            EnvironmentList = new ObservableCollection<mJob_Select_Environment>(dsEnvironmentList);

            //Orders List
            var dsSLEVENOrders = _dc.get_SLORDER_List(SelectedEnvironmentID).ToList();
            SelectOrderList = new List<mJob_Select_OrderList>(dsSLEVENOrders);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public Models.mJob_Select mJobSelectSettings { get { return _mJobSelectSettings; } set { _mJobSelectSettings = value; } }

        public int SelectedEnvironmentID { get { return mJobSelectSettings.EnvironmentID; } set { if (mJobSelectSettings.EnvironmentID != value) { mJobSelectSettings.EnvironmentID = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EnvironmentID"); } } }

        public ObservableCollection<mJob_Select_Environment> EnvironmentList { get; set; }

        public List<mJob_Select_OrderList> SelectOrderList { get; set; }
}
```

So basically `EnvironmentList` is pulled from a view in the database and I can populate an `ObservableCollection` successfully. The `SelectedOrderList` is the result of a stored procedure and I'm trying to load this result into a list object of some sort.

The error I'm getting is

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'

I was able to implement this successfully in the code behind on the view but I'm trying to adhere to MVVM and making my ViewModel do the work.

```
using (SLEVEN_CLASS.dbSLEVENDataContext dbSLEVEN = new SLEVEN_CLASS.dbSLEVENDataContext())
{
    var dsSLEVENOrders = dbSLEVEN.get_SLORDER_List(intENVID);
    lvSlevenJobs.ItemsSource = dsSLEVENOrders;
    lvSlevenJobs.SelectedValuePath = "SL_ID";
}
```

I've been searching and trying to figure this out for awhile now and I've tried to implement some solutions that I've found here and there to no avail. One involved looping through the `IResult` and adding each row to the model another suggested building a more complex linq query instead of a stored procedure. None of these options are out of the question. Is there a generally accepted method for performing this task?

Thanks in advance to any answers/suggestions you can provide!

**//EDIT//**
I believe I've found my solution. I was trying to return my SPROC results to a model that I created but when using LINQ a Model is created automatically called Procedure Name + 'Result'.

I declared my list to utilize the 'Result' model like so:

```
public List<get_SLORDER_ListResult> SelectOrderList { get; set; }
List<get_SLORDER_ListResult> lstSLEVENOrders = _dc.get_SLORDER_List(SelectedEnvironmentID).ToList<get_SLORDER_ListResult>();
            SelectOrderList = new List<get_SLORDER_ListResult>(lstSLEVENOrders);
```

I then bound my ListView to SelectOrderList.

Comment: _"The error I'm getting"_ -- where are you getting that error? Why are you trying to assign a list object to an `int` variable? Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem and shows clearly what you're trying to accomplish. In the meantime, consider just assigning `SelectOrderList` directly: `SelectOrderList = _dc.get_SLORDER_List(SelectedEnvironmentID).ToList();`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter. I think I've found the solution I was looking for. The problem was when you call a SPROC as I was doing above it returns an ISingleResult object. That's probably why intellisense was trying to convert it to an int instead of a List. I appreciate your time.